# Can Linux be configured to wait for USB storage to be reattached instead of returning I/O error

Tags: linux, files, mount, usb-drive

If a `usb_storage` device is physically detached from an Ubuntu machine while it is still mounted, any attempt to access the file system will produce an I/O error.

Is there some way to configure Linux such that instead of producing an I/O error, the process will block until the device is reattached (or the process is killed using `SIGKILL`)?

Ideally I'd like to see a dialogue similar to [what AmigaOS would produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AURwv.png) for a removed floppy. But even if it silently blocks waiting for me to figure out that I need to reattach the USB device, that would still work better for me than an I/O error.

Comment: Should be doable with an automounter.

Comment: @Gilles The automounter would only help if the file system was unused for long enough to get unmounted before the USB device was removed. In my case processes will have open files on the file system preventing the automounter from unmounting it in the first place.